# How to export data from Google Chat?

Tags: export, backup, google-chat

At [1] Google promises that data can be exported from Google Chat.
However:

1. At Google Takeout page [2] in `Select data to include` there is no `Chat` product.
2. In the exported `.zip` archive there is no `Chat` folder with the Google Chat exported data.

Very confused. How to export data from Google Chat?

[1] https://support.google.com/chat/answer/10126829?hl=en

[2] https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout

Comment: Following this.  I'm also wanting this feature. not sure why we can't copy a chat.  Google obviously paranoid about people's privacy ?  I use it for work chats, so I need it for tracking conversations and useful links, shared knowledge etc...   I did try "select all" and copy paste into a txt document, but the formatting is horrible

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous - I found a workaround (July 2022) to make a download / backup of Google Chat text that does not require Google Takeout.

I am not sure how long this workaround will last, since this method seems to rely on 'Google Hangouts' - which I understand is being deprecated.

To export / backup your Google Chat do this:

1. Go to the Gmail account that was used for the chat. Enter into the search bar:  in:chats
2. This should bring up a list of chats you have participated in.
3. Click on the chat you wish to save or copy - it should open all of the threads of that chat in a list - (it looks similar to threaded /nested gmail conversation).
4. Click on the Print All icon (printer icon) top right of the gmail window, which should then open a print dialogue box.
5. For me, this allowed me to "cancel" the actual print dialogue box, and then I am left with a single html page showing the formatted entire chat thread, which I was then able to copy and paste into a new email or wherever.

If it works for you, give me an upvote :-)

Hope this method stays available as it's better than nothing.

I followed this article to discover this method...

https://www.nucleustechnologies.com/blog/manual-guide-to-backup-google-hangouts-chats/

Answer (score -1):

The exported data from Google Chat is seems to be located in `Hangouts` folder.